# Adding conditions to my method in order to reduce user error

Tags: java

I have attempted to add conditions inside my add method so when the user makes a mistake like entering a new appointment with values that already exist the program will produce a **error message**

**here is my add method**

```
public void add(Appointment a){
    appointmentList.add(a);


}
```

my question is how would I do get the program to produce an error message ?
I have already attempt to use try and catch.

Comment: I don't really see a question in this post, nor the code you are talking about.

Comment: public class AppointmentBook {

private static final int NOTFOUND =-1;

private ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentList= new ArrayList<Appointment>();

public void add(Appointment a){
 appointmentList.add(a);
 
 
}

Comment: Please use code blocks to share code and please put it in your original message. Also, ask a question.

Comment: update your question with the code, and use code blocks. still no question

Comment: try and catch are used to handle exceptions. What you need is to throw an exception, to signal the problem. Not to handle it. Read the Java exceptions tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `throw` to throw a specific exception and handle it later to preview an error message to user.
for Example :

```
public void add(Appointment a){
    if(a==null){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("appointement can't be null");
    }
    appointmentList.add(a);


}
```

You can also create a specific `AppointementAlreadyExistException` by extending `RunTimeException` and throw it when it is needed :

```
    public class AppointementAlreadyExistException extends RuntimeException{
    // constructors
    }
```

and use it as follows :

```
 public void add(Appointment a){
        if(a==null){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("appointement can't be null");
        }
    //equals in appointement must be overrided to give correct behaviour 
    if(appointmentList!=null && appointmentList.contains(a)){
       throw new AppointementAlreadyExistException();
    }
    appointmentList.add(a);


    }
```

Now when you call this method :

```
     // let's assume we have an Appointement a
 try {

    add(a)

   }catch(AppointementAlreadyExistException ex){
    //display the information to the user saying that appointment 
   }
```

Comment: appreciated for your help rafik